# Autofac mock - How do I setup/fake data from specific methods in dependencies?

Tags: c#, moq, autofac, xunit

I'm new to both unit tests, Autofac and mocks so likely, this is relatively easy, but I'm having a hard time figure it out.

I have this class `SystemUnderTest` with one dependency, and two methods `GetValueOne` and `GetValueTwo`.

```
public class SystemUnderTest : ISystemUnderTest
{
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;

    public SystemUnderTest(IDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public string GetValueOne()
    {
        return _dependency.GetValueOne();
    }

    public string GetValueTwo()
    {
        return _dependency.GetValueTwo();
    }
}

public interface ISystemUnderTest
{
    string GetValueOne();
    string GetValueTwo();
}
```

These methods gets data from the dependency.

```
public class Dependency : IDependency
{
    public string GetValueOne()
    {
        return "get-value-one";
    }
    public string GetValueTwo()
    {
        return "get-value-two";
    }
}

public interface IDependency
{
    string GetValueOne();
    string GetValueTwo();
}
```

I'm trying to fake the data from one of the methods (the "`GetValueTwo`") so its returning `"expected value"` instead of `"get-value-two"` which is what the dependency normally returns.

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test_SystemUnderTest()
{
    using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
    {
        // Setup
        mock.Mock<IDependency>().Setup(x => x.GetValueTwo()).Returns("expected value");

        // Configure
        mock.Provide<IDependency, Dependency>();

        // Arrange - configure the mock
        var sut = mock.Create<SystemUnderTest>();

        // Act
        var actual_GetValueOne = sut.GetValueOne();
        var actual_GetValueTwo = sut.GetValueTwo();

        // Assert - assert on the mock
        Assert.Equal("get-value-one", actual_GetValueOne);
        Assert.Equal("expected value", actual_GetValueTwo);
    }
}
```

The first part in my test, the `Setup` piece, does not seem to have any effect, and its probably because I'm doing some basic stuff wrong.

Anyone with insights on how to save my day?

Comment: The configure/provide is overriding the setup. Why are you providing the dependency implementation to begin with?

Comment: Just noticed something. Why is the Test async if nothing is being awaited?

Comment: @Nkosi I simplified the code for this question and forgot to remove the async

Comment: Noted. This is an interesting question. I would suggest you take note of how I edited/reformatted the question to allow for better reading flow and understanding of your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The members of `Dependency` implementation would need to have virtual members for them to be able to be overridden when doing a partial mocked.

```
public class Dependency : IDependency {
    public virtual string GetValueOne() {
        return "get-value-one";
    }
    public virtual string GetValueTwo() {
        return "get-value-two";
    }
}
```

Then similar to what was suggested in another answer you would instead mock the implementation,  making sure to enable it to call base members and only setup the members you need to override.

```
public void Test_SystemUnderTest() {
    using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose()) {
        // Setup
        var dependency = mock.Mock<Dependency>();
        dependency.CallBase = true;
        dependency.Setup(x => x.GetValueTwo()).Returns("expected value");

        // Configure
        mock.Provide<IDependency>(dependency.Object);

        // Arrange - configure the mock
        var sut = mock.Create<SystemUnderTest>();

        // Act
        var actual_GetValueOne = sut.GetValueOne();
        var actual_GetValueTwo = sut.GetValueTwo();

        // Assert - assert on the mock
        Assert.AreEqual("get-value-one", actual_GetValueOne);
        Assert.AreEqual("expected value", actual_GetValueTwo);
    }
}
```

The above passes when exercised provided that the members of the implementation that need to be mocked can be overridden (ie `virtual`).

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert in writing unit tests, but I'm pretty sure that by using `Provide` with two type arguments, you overwrite the `Setup` part you did previously. By my understanding, the `Provide` method should be used to provide your own mock implementation of target interface, so using both `Provide` with two type arguments and `Setup` for the same dependency doesn't make sense.

So you can either modify the `Dependency` implementation's `GetValueTwo` to return `"expected value"` and use the rest of your code unmodified, or you can supply the mocked instance to the `Provide` method with one type argument, with both of the methods previously setup, like this:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test_SystemUnderTest()
    {
        using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
        {
            var mockedDependency = mock.Mock<IDependency>();

            // Setup
            mockedDependency.Setup(x => x.GetValueOne()).Returns("get-value-one");
            mockedDependency.Setup(x => x.GetValueTwo()).Returns("expected value");

            // The following line is not even necessary
            mock.Provide<IDependency>(mockedDependency.Object);

            // Arrange - configure the mock
            var sut = mock.Create<SystemUnderTest>();

            // Act
            var actual_GetValueOne = sut.GetValueOne();
            var actual_GetValueTwo = sut.GetValueTwo();

            // Assert - assert on the mock
            Assert.Equal("get-value-one", actual_GetValueOne);
            Assert.Equal("expected value", actual_GetValueTwo);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can remove the provide altogether since you already setup  all the members on the mock

Comment: @Nkosi yep - just tested, provide in this case is not needed at all

Comment: @JimmieAndersson are the members of the implementation virtual?

Comment: @DejanJanjušević Thanks, but I don't want to Setup all the methods on the dependency interface since there is a lot of logic in other methods I want to use/test together with the SystemUnderTest implementation.

That's why I tried to provide a specific implementation of the IDependency, so it would use those, and then I only want to Setup specific methods.

Comment: @Nkosi they are not virtual

Comment: @JimmieAndersson check my suggested answer

Comment: @Nkosi wow thanks, that really did the job! and it also made my day